# Using the iOS Accelerate Framework for Data Smoothing

Tags: ios

Does anyone have any pointers to using the Accelerate Framework for Data Smoothing...? I am looking to smooth data based on inputs to the accelerometers. I currently do some basic filtering of incoming accelerometer data points and then pass the data to a function that then performs some calculations based on this. I then would like to do some further data smoothing on the processed data.

I currently have a prototype that uses a Python library that performs a Savitzky-Golay filter on the resulting data. I then use the output from that in my App. My prototype calculates data nicely, however I want to do this in either Objective-C / Swift. I would also like to use the Accelerate Framework for performance reasons. So far I haven't seen any pointers to how I could use the Accelerate Framework for data smoothing, hence my question.

If any one has any pointers or documentation, then please let me know.

Thanks,

J

Comment: Can the people who are down-voting this please indicate why...? Seems to be a completely legitimate question. I'm asking for pointers as I've found the documentation to be a bit terse. Thanks.

Comment: did you find solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably use vDSP_conv [Apple Docu](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_conv) to do the convolution with the Savitzky-Golay filter. You don't need the Framework to create the kernel, so using this function should be enough.

You can find example code on how to use that function here (You may need apple developer credentials to review that code)
[Apple Example Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/vDSPExamples/Listings/DemonstrateConvolution_c.html)

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how to apply Savitzky-Golay filter with vDSP_conv OR I want to know how to apply Savitzky-Golay filter to an array of float with  iOS swift

Comment: did you find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need in my project. I had two arrays of `Double` containing times and positions from a linear encoder. Positions were perturbed so I wanted to smooth them.

I did an import:

```
import Accelerate
```

Then used the function `vDSP.convolve()`:

```
var myTimes: [Double] = //populate with your data (aka x axis)
var myLengths: [Double] = //populate with your data (aka y axis)
    
let convTimes = vDSP.convolve(myTimes, withKernel: [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
let convLengths = vDSP.convolve(myLengths, withKernel: [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
```

That's it, in Swift 5.

Original:

[image: Original data plotted]

Smooth:

[image: Smooth data plotted]